# Changing the height of cell depending on text height

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uikit

I want to show a tableView with dynamic cell height. I found a way to change the height of my prototype cell in a tableView manually using this code. In this case the height is 400.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return CGFloat (400)
     }
```

In my cell the first part with the username (green and red) and the last part with the likes (yellow) has a fixed height with for example 60.
The height of the part in the middle (blue) should change depending on the text. So how can I do that?

I tried to get the label height with this.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
       userComment.sizeToFit()
       print(userComment.bounds.size.height)
    }
```

But this always shows me 18. My aim is to use the first code above and `return CGFloat ( 60 + 60 + dynamic label/userComment height)`

This is how my tableView looks like.

```
extension ViewComments: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return table.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
        let video: importComment
        video = table[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.userName.text = video.userName
        cell.userGroup.text = poiNavigationName.title
        cell.userComment.text = video.userComment
        cell.userTime.text = "\(video.userTime!)"
        cell.userLikes.text = "\(video.userLikes!)"
        cell.userName.text = video.userName
        cell.commentId.text = video.commentId
        cell.kommentarCount.text = "\(video.kommentarCount!)"
        
        cell.buttonAction = { [unowned self] in
            let selectedIndexPath = table[indexPath.row].commentId!
            ViewComments.commentIDNew = selectedIndexPath
        }
        return cell
    }
    /*
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return CGFloat (400)
     }*/
    
}
```

[image]

Updated Picture after removing heightForRowAt and awakeFromNib
[image]

Comment: It seems like you're overthinking this. Throw away your `heightForRow` and `awakeFromNib` implementations.  Autolayout will do all this for you automatically.

Comment: I did what you said but it does not really work. Please look at the updated picture above.

Comment: You didn't do what I said at all. You didn't use autolayout. Use it.

Comment: You mean working with constraints? I did that. Please look at updated content above.

Comment: Then you did it wrong. I don't know what your constraints are. But with the right constraints, this will behave exactly as you described.

Comment: Is it possible that I restricted the height somewhere else? I clicked on prototype cell and the id inspector showed me 200 as cell height. I removed the value but still same.

Comment: Anything is _possible_. I can think about a million ways to do this _wrong_. But what I'm saying is that there is also a way to do it _right_.

Comment: Thank you I solved it now following the tutorial at my comment.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return CGFloat (400)
}
```

instead of using a hard coded value you can use a dynamic height.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614961-automaticdimension

Comment: I tried it like this but then the height of the cell was like 1 instead. Right now it is manually edited to 200. So it did shrink a lot using your code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you're describing something like this:

[image]

That's done *entirely* with the internal autolayout constraints of the prototype cell. You should not attempt to do this manually by returning a specific height for each cell; just let the runtime do it for you. It knows how to do this a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it not following this tutorial and it works great. [Tutorial](https://fluffy.es/dynamic-height-tableview-cell/)